# Download File from Dropbox in Node.js cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

I'm writing a node.js cli to learn HTTP requests. I'd like to download a file and save it to the local folder. The issue I have is with getting the file from Dropbox. I've been reading their API for a day or so and still don't understand how to navigate it. Here's my code:

```
var https = require('https'),
    clc = require('cli-color'),
    options = {
        protocol: 'https:',
        hostname: 'www.dropbox.com',
        path: '/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<<my-id>>response_type=code',
        method: 'GET'
    },
    token;

var req = https.get(options, function (res) {
    if (res) {
        console.log(clc.green('success'));
    }

    res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

I'm following the `code` OAuth authorization flow from Dropbox's API. When I run the `index.js` file, the data it returns is something like this:

```
<Buffer 6f 6d 70 6f 6e 65 6e 74 73 5f 5f 69 6e 70 75 74 2e 54 65 78 74 49 6e 70 75 74 2c 20 5b 5d 29 3b 20 7d 28 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 73 5f 5f 63 6c 65 61 6e 5f ... >
```

Is this the auth code? If not, what do I do to get it and store it?

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a `Buffer` containing some of the raw response data. You can concatenate each `data` until the response is finished. I should point out that the response appears to be javascript (if you convert the Buffer to string or otherwise convert the hex bytes to a string), so you might try something like:

```
https.get(options, function(res) {
  var buf = '';
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    buf += data;
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('Response:');
    console.log(buf);
  });
});
```

Also `protocol: 'https:',` is not necessary and isn't used for by the `https` module.

Comment: Thanks! Concatenating them results in a bunch of HTML that compiles to a login page.  What do I do from here? Is there a way to insert login credentials and/or acquire an access code from here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with their web service to answer that. As far as making the request and buffering the entire response goes, that I can answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a bit.